# Need help to draw a X for Tic Tac Toe in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, tic-tac-toe, p5.js

I was following a tutorial on Youtube (The Coding Train) which was making a minesweeper game. I followed the video until I had make a X.
I want to make to lines that cross each other and form a big x like this:

[The board with a X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkDLX.png)
[image: The board with a X]

The problem I have is that I do not know how to that with each cell.

I have a Cell class:

```
function Cell(x, y, w) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.busy = true;
    this.player = true;
    this.computer = true;
}

Cell.prototype.show = function() {
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.w);
    if (true) {
        line(0, 0, 100, 100);
        line(0, 100, 100, 0);
    }
}
```

And the main code is:

```
function make2DArray(cols, rows) {
    var arr = new Array(cols);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(rows);
    }
    return arr;
}

var grid;
var rows;
var cols;
var w = 100;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(300, 300);
    cols = floor(width/w);
    rows = floor(width/w);
    grid = make2DArray(cols, rows);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = new Cell(i * w, j * w, w);
        }
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            grid[i][j].show();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call a X when a player clicks on a cell, and display it. The line needs to be in the Cell class in Show object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate of the top left corner of each `Cell` is stored in the `x` and `y` properties. The width is stored in `w`.
So a cross over the entire `Cell` can be draw by:

```
line(this.x, this.y, this.x+this.w-1, this.y+this.w-1);
line(this.x, this.y+this.w-1, this.x+this.w-1, this.y);
```

To draw a cross in a `Cell` dependent on a click into the cell, you have to init the `player` property by `false`:

```
function Cell(x, y, w) {

    .......

    this.player = false;
}
```

Draw the cross it the `Cell` dependent on the `player` property:

```
Cell.prototype.show = function() {
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w-1, this.w-1);
    if (this.player) {
        line(this.x, this.y, this.x+this.w-1, this.y+this.w-1);
        line(this.x, this.y+this.w-1, this.x+this.w-1, this.y);
    }
}
```

Create a function which checks if a point is in the `Cell` and set the `player` property `true`, if the test succeeds:

```
Cell.prototype.testX = function(px, py) {
    if (px >= this.x && px < this.x+this.w && py >= this.y && py < this.y+this.w ) {
        this.player = true;
    }
}
```

Add a `mousePressed` event, and call the test function `testX` for each `Cell`. if the mouse position is in a cell, then the `player` property of the `Cell` will become `true` and a cross will appear in the `Cell` at the next `draw`:

```
function mousePressed() {
    if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                grid[i][j].testX(mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
function Cell(x, y, w) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.busy = true;
    this.computer = true;
    
    this.player = false;
}

Cell.prototype.show = function() {
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w-1, this.w-1);
    if (this.player) {
        line(this.x, this.y, this.x+this.w-1, this.y+this.w-1);
        line(this.x, this.y+this.w-1, this.x+this.w-1, this.y);
    }
}

Cell.prototype.testX = function(px, py) {
    if (px >= this.x && px < this.x+this.w && py >= this.y && py < this.y+this.w ) {
        this.player = true;
    }
}

function mousePressed() {
    if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                grid[i][j].testX(mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        }
    }
}

function make2DArray(cols, rows) {
    var arr = new Array(cols);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(rows);
    }
    return arr;
}

var grid;
var rows;
var cols;
var w = 100;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(300, 300);
    cols = floor(width/w);
    rows = floor(width/w);
    grid = make2DArray(cols, rows);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = new Cell(i * w, j * w, w);
        }
   }
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            grid[i][j].show();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for tye great answer. Will have look at it!